# Swift Import Statements No Longer Necessary

Tags: xcode, swift

With the latest update to Swift, I'm able to use classes, functions, etc. from Foundation and UIKit without having to include the import statements for them. If I add the import statement in Xcode, it shows it crossed out, as if it's depreciated.

Is it no longer necessary to include import statements for some modules like Foundation and UIKit in Swift?

Comment: That seems really odd.

Comment: So does this mean that if I have an application with 5 Swift files that all use UIKit, I only need to import UIKit in one of the files to use it in all 5 files?

Comment: Still do i need to import in each file. When i create a new file its alerady imported

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug in Xcode 7.3.0. As you said, if you continue to import it, there shouldn't be Amy problems. My guess is that we will see an update in the coming days or weeks to fix some of the bugs. Apple is getting ready to release Xcode 8 with Swift 3 in June and are getting the program ready for the switchover.